# Echoing Shortcode content inside the loop

Tags: shortcode

Im trying to echo the content from inside shortcodes into a conditional.
I have two shortcodes like this:

```
function fb_fans( $atts, $content = null ) { return $content; }
add_shortcode( 'fans', 'fb_fans' );

function fb_nonfans( $atts, $content = null ) { return $content; }
add_shortcode( 'nonfans', 'fb_nonfans' );
```

then inside the loop I want echo content that the user puts inside... 
[fans] echo this content [/fans] and also
[nonfans] else echo this [/nonfans]

heres what I have that obviously doesnt work

```
if ($like_status) { echo $fb_fans; } else {  echo $fb_nonfans; }
```

anyone know how to write this correctly???
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Use the actual function if you want to programatically call the shortcode.

```
echo fb_fans($atts, $content);
```

UPDATE:

Well, I think you need to go back to learning how shortcodes work. You simply need to use `the_content()` to display shortcodes properly.

Within your content area, you the user would type:

```
[fans]FOOBAR[/fans]
```

This would output FOOBAR inside of the content. A shortcode is basically a way to use PHP functions within the content area safely.

Comment: unfortunately its coming up blank. scratching my head because two of you had the same answer. Maybe i need to add something to my loop to get content? heres the whole loop.......  

`if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post(); 

if ($like_status) { echo fb_fans($atts, $content); } else { echo fb_nonfans($atts, $content); } 

endwhile; endif;`

Comment: You have to declare the variables $atts and $content to contain some sort of data.

Comment: any idea of how to do that, when I want to only echo what the user puts inside of each shortcode?

Comment: youre definitely right about learning shortcodes. this is a very simple shortcode. instead of `return $content` i tried `return do_shortcode($content);` I think it made a difference. Where Im getting tripped us is how to write a conditional, where one shortcode content is the if, and other is the else.

Comment: Why not use a FB plugin to do all of this? There are plenty out there. :)

Comment: Theres one plugin that actually works, facebook tab manager, and it only partially works. Im at a loss. Theres got to be some way to echo the contents of a shortcode in a conditional statement inside the loop.

Comment: Technically, the_content() renders the shortcode.  You should create a one shortcode that does the conditional logic within the shortcode function itself.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `do_shortcode` built in WordPress function as shown below:

```
if ($like_status) { 
  echo do_shortcode('[fb_fans]'); 
} else {  
  echo do_shortcode('[fb_nonfans]'); 
}
```

Please refer [`do_shortcode`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/do_shortcode/) official documentation.